# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'int'

Tags: python, numpy, attributeerror

I tried to run my code in another computer, while it successfully compiled in the original environment, this error can outta nowhere:

```
File "c:\vision_hw\hw_3\cv2IP.py", line 91, in SECOND_ORDER_LOG
    original = np.zeros((5,5),dtype=np.int)
File "C:\Users\brian2lee\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 284, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute " AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'int'
```

I have tried reinstallin numpy but it did not work. Down below is my code:

```
def SECOND_ORDER_LOG (self,img):
    original = np.zeros((5,5),dtype=np.int)
    original[2,2] = 1
    kernel = np.array([[ 0,  0, -1,  0,  0],
    [ 0, -1, -2, -1,  0],
    [-1, -2, 16, -2, -1],
    [ 0, -1, -2, -1,  0],
    [ 0,  0, -1,  0,  0]])
    result = original + 1 * kernel
    sharpened = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, result)
    return sharpened
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`numpy.int` was [deprecated in NumPy 1.20](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations) and was [removed in NumPy 1.24](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.24.0-notes.html#expired-deprecations).

You can change it to `numpy.int_`, or just `int`.

Answer (score 5):

```
np.int = np.int32
np.float = np.float64
np.bool = np.bool_

boruta = BorutaPy(estimator=rf)
boruta.fit(x, y)
```

from [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/boruta_py/issues/122#issuecomment-1914122968)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing (AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'int') suggests that you're trying to use numpy.int, which isn't an attribute in numpy. However, there's numpy.int_, which is the exact equivalent of Python's built-in int but it's available for array operations inside numpy.

**If you're not working within the numpy framework for the task causing this error, it's recommended to simply use Python's built-in int.**

numpy.int (along with other similar types) was deprecated in NumPy 1.20 and subsequently removed in NumPy 1.24. Therefore, using numpy.int in versions after 1.24 will raise an error. Since **numpy.int** is now removed, using native Python's **int** type is the easiest replacement when numpy's specific capabilities aren't needed.