How can I solve import mxnet error “module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool’”?
I’m using google colab with Python version 3.8.5 to run 'import mxnet as mx'.
But it returns "module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'"
Actually this command worked really well last December(12.2023) and January(01.2024).
So I don't know why it doesn't work today.
How can I fix this error? If anyone knows please help.
My code is :
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

!wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.5/Python-3.8.5.tgz
!tar xvfz Python-3.8.5.tgz
!Python-3.8.5/configure
!make
!sudo make install

!pip install torch==1.6.0+cpu torchvision==0.7.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
!pip install --upgrade gluoncv
!pip install --upgrade mxnet

import mxnet as mx
from mxnet import image
from mxnet.gluon.data.vision import transforms

import gluoncv
from gluoncv.utils.viz import get_color_pallete
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from gluoncv.data.ade20k.segmentation import ADE20KSegmentation
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from gluoncv.data.transforms.presets.segmentation import test_transform
from google.colab import files

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

and this it results :
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mxnet/numpy/utils.py:37: FutureWarning: In the future `np.bool` will be defined as the corresponding NumPy scalar.
  bool = onp.bool
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d07a1bcfa66c> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import mxnet as mx
      2 from mxnet import image
      3 from mxnet.gluon.data.vision import transforms
      4 import gluoncv
      5 

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py in __getattr__(attr)
    317 
    318         if attr in __former_attrs__:
--> 319             raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
    320 
    321         if attr == 'testing':

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'.
`np.bool` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations


Similar answer as for https://stackoverflow.com/q/74946845/674039

for people who have the same error, I solved the error like this.
by moving "import numpy~" before "import mxnet~"
and adding "np.bool = np.bool_" between them.
import numpy as np
np.bool = np.bool_

import mxnet as mx
from mxnet import image
from mxnet.gluon.data.vision import transforms

import gluoncv
from gluoncv.utils.viz import get_color_pallete
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from gluoncv.data.ade20k.segmentation import ADE20KSegmentation
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from gluoncv.data.transforms.presets.segmentation import test_transform
from google.colab import files

import pandas as pd
import os


Your pip install commands don't pin any transitive dependencies, so back in December and January you will have gotten an older version of NumPy.
Looking at the source for NumPy, that message has been added in a commit that first shipped with NumPy 1.25.0.
Try downgrading NumPy to a version older than that, as a band-aid:
!pip install 'numpy<1.25.0'


I tried following your advice and downgraded Numpy version, but it doesn’t work yet..
Anyway, thank you so much.

Is there a new/different error message? If so, edit that into your original question.

No, there was no change in the error message

Then I would suggest double-checking you're installing these packages in the right environment – there should have been a change...

I solved the error! "import numpy as np" before "import mxnet as mx" and between them, I add "np.bool = np.bool_", then it runs.
